# Change the width of images with same class uniformly using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple images that have the same class attribute and I want to resize all the images uniformly even though they all have different original widths - how can I do this using jQuery?

```
<img id=img1 class="ResizeMe" src="img1.gif" width="100" height="100" /><br />

<img id=img2 class="ResizeMe" src="img2.gif" width="200" height="200" /><br />

<img id=img3 class="ResizeMe" src="img3.gif" width="150" height="150" /><br />

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Shrink Images by 10%" />
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Grow Images by 10%" />
```

TIA!

UPDATE:  Here's the final working code I used for anyone hitting this in the future...

```
        function OnClientValueChanging(sender, args) 
        {
            var zoomPercentage = args.get_newValue() / 100;

            $(".ApplyZoomEffect").each(function () {
                var newWidth = parseFloat($(this).attr('OriginalWidth')) * zoomPercentage;
                var newHeight = parseFloat($(this).attr('OriginalHeight')) * zoomPercentage;
                $(this).css('width', newWidth + "px").css('height', newHeight + "px");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this style:

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
  $(".ResizeMe").width(function(i, w) { return w * 0.9 })
                .height(function(i, h) { return h * 0.9 });
});

$("#Button2").click(function() {
  $(".ResizeMe").width(function(i, w) { return w * 1.1 })
                .height(function(i, h) { return h * 1.1 });
});
```

Since **jQuery 1.4.1**, you can pass a function to [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to accomplish this more cleanly.

Comment: Woops, had the buttons backwards, fixed now.

Comment: Nick, I'm using telerik RadControls which uses v1.3.2.  So does this mean i cannot use this technique?

Comment: @EdenMachine - Not on your current version, however Service Pack 2 for RadControls is out, just install that upgrade and you can move to jQuery 1.4.

Comment: It's actually the Q1 2010 and it's still in beta at the moment so I'll upgrade after the final release: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-what-is-new.html
http://www.telerik.com/community/labs/radcontrols-for-asp-net-ajax-q1-2010-beta.aspx

Answer (score 1):

$('.ResizeMe').attr("width",value)

Comment: The example above increases or decreases the size by a percentage, your solution is great for an absolute width for all images but if they have different initial sizes then it fails.

Comment: also... you'd need to use "each" as it'll return an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Button2').click(function() {
    $('.ResizeMe').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('width', parseInt($(this).attr('width')) * 110 / 100)
    });
});
```

Button1 is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You could just multiply by 1.1 rather than 110/100 ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $('.ResizeMe').each(function(){
       var w=$(this).width;
       var newWidth=//calculate new width depending on which button pressed
       $(this).attr('width',newWidth);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ResizeMe").attr('width', '100');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('#Button1').click(function() {
    $('.ResizeMe').width(function(index, oldWidth) { return oldWidth * .9; })
                  .height(function(index, oldHeight) { return oldHeight * .9; });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$("img").each(function(i){
  this.width *= 1.1;
  this.width *= 1.1;
})
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't check whether it was correct. I have fixed the code now